Unable to find qualifying bean in @Configuration file
I'm a new user of @ConfigurationProperties, and I've been searching for/working at a solution to this issue for some time. I have a property file reading application.properties, and it's working under some circumstances - but not all. For instance, I autowired an instance in a controller, and the value comes back in Postman properly; however, it's for connection parameters, and I'm extending AbstractMongoClientConfiguration to hold the beans generating the MongoClient and MongoTemplate. I'm consistently getting this error; I'm drop the full stack later.
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoGeneral': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'mongoProperties': No qualifying bean of type 'com.mistermorse.flawlessbeansjavaspringapi.config.MongoProperties' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}

Here's my @ConfigurationProperties file.
package com.mistermorse.flawlessbeansjavaspringapi.config;

import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;

@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.data.mongodb")
public class MongoProperties {

    private String uri;

    @Bean
    public MongoProperties mongoProperties() {
        return new MongoProperties();
    }

    public String getUri() {
        return uri;
    }

    public void setUri(String uri) {
        this.uri = uri;
    }

}

I didn't have the constructor at first, but I put it in for a test. Speaking of tests, my controller looks like this.
package com.mistermorse.flawlessbeansjavaspringapi.controller;

import com.mistermorse.flawlessbeansjavaspringapi.config.MongoProperties;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    MongoProperties mongoProperties = new MongoProperties();

    @GetMapping("/database")
    public MongoProperties getMongoProperties() {
        return mongoProperties;
    }

}

And, for the third piece, this is my application file.
package com.mistermorse.flawlessbeansjavaspringapi;

import com.mistermorse.flawlessbeansjavaspringapi.config.MongoGeneral;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesScan;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;

@SpringBootApplication
@ConfigurationPropertiesScan("com.mistermorse.flawlessbeansjavaspringapi")
public class FlawlessBeansJavaSpringApiApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext applicationContext = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(MongoGeneral.class);
        SpringApplication.run(FlawlessBeansJavaSpringApiApplication.class, args);
    }

}

That @ConfigurationPropertiesScan path includes my whole project, and properly returns the properties when the resource it's bound to is hit. However, when I autowire the same resource in the same way in this connection reference, I get the error mentioned above.
package com.mistermorse.flawlessbeansjavaspringapi.config;

import com.mongodb.client.MongoClient;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoClients;
import com.mongodb.lang.NonNull;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.config.AbstractMongoClientConfiguration;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
@Configuration
public class MongoGeneral extends AbstractMongoClientConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    MongoProperties mongoProperties = new MongoProperties();

    @NonNull
    @Override
    protected String getDatabaseName() {
        return placeholderString;
    }

    @Bean(name = "getSimpleMongoClient")
    MongoClient getSimpleMongoClient() {
        System.out.println(mongoProperties.getUsername());
        return MongoClients.create(placeholderString);
    }

}

I don't understand the problem, and I'm wondering my mind is having difficulty fully abstracting the interactions. Here's the full error.
C:\Users\matth\.jdks\openjdk-21.0.2\bin\java.exe -XX:TieredStopAtLevel=1 -Dspring.output.ansi.enabled=always -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dspring.jmx.enabled=true -Dspring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain -Dspring.application.admin.enabled=true "-Dmanagement.endpoints.jmx.exposure.include=*" "-javaagent:C:\Users\matth\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2023.3.4\lib\idea_rt.jar=54655:C:\Users\matth\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2023.3.4\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Dsun.stdout.encoding=UTF-8 -Dsun.stderr.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath C:\Users\matth\IdeaProjects\flawless-beans-java-spring-api\target\classes;C:\Users\matth\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb\3.2.5\spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb-3.2.5.jar;C:\Users\matth\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter\3.2.5\spring-boot-starter-3.2.5.jar;C:\Users\matth\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot\3.2.5\spring-boot-3.2.5.jar;C:\Users\matth\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-autoconfigure\3.2.5\spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.2.5.jar;C:\Users\matth\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-logging\3.2.5\spring-boot-starter-logging-3.2.5.jar;C:\Users\matth\.m2\repository\ch\qos\logback\logback-classic\1.4.14\logback-classic-1.4.14.jar;C:\Users\matth\.m2\repository\ch\qos\logback\logback-core\1.4.14\logback-core-1.4.14.jar;C:\Users\matth\.m2\repository\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-to-slf4j\2.21.1\log4j-to-slf4j-2.21.1.jar;C:\Users\matth\.m2\repository\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-api\2.21.1\log4j-api-2.21.1.jar;C:\Users\matth\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\jul-to-slf4j\2.0.13\jul-to-slf4j-2.0.13.jar;C:\Users\matth\.m2\repository\jakarta\annotation\jakarta.annotation-api\2.1.1\jakarta.annotation-api-2.1.1.jar;C:\Users\matth\.m2\repository\org\yaml\snakeyaml\2.2\snakeyaml-2.2.jar;C:\Users\matth\.m2\repository\org\mongodb\mongodb-driver-sync\4.11.2\mongodb-driver-sync-4.11.2.jar;C:\Users\matth\.m2\repository\org\mongodb\bson\4.11.2\bson-4.11.2.jar;C:\Users\matth\.m2\repository\org\mongodb\mongodb-driver-core\4.11.2\mongodb-driver-core-4.11.2.jar;C:\Users\matth\.m2\repository\org\mongodb\bson-record-codec\4.11.2\bson-record-codec-4.11.2.jar;C:\Users\matth\.m2\repository\org\springframework\data\spring-data-mongodb\4.2.5\spring-data-mongodb-4.2.5.jar;C:\Users\matth\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-tx\6.1.6\spring-tx-6.1.6.jar;C:\Users\matth\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-context\6.1.6\spring-context-6.1.6.jar;C:\Users\matth\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-beans\6.1.6\spring-beans-6.1.6.jar;C:\Users\matth\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-expression\6.1.6\spring-expression-6.1.6.jar;C:\Users\matth\.m2\repository\org\springframework\data\spring-data-commons\3.2.5\spring-data-commons-3.2.5.jar;C:\Users\matth\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\slf4j-api\2.0.13\slf4j-api-2.0.13.jar;C:\Users\matth\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-data-rest\3.2.5\spring-boot-starter-data-rest-3.2.5.jar;C:\Users\matth\.m2\repository\org\springframework\data\spring-data-rest-webmvc\4.2.5\spring-data-rest-webmvc-4.2.5.jar;C:\Users\matth\.m2\repository\org\springframework\data\spring-data-rest-core\4.2.5\spring-data-rest-core-4.2.5.jar;C:\Users\matth\.m2\repository\org\atteo\evo-inflector\1.3\evo-inflector-1.3.jar;C:\Users\matth\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-databind\2.15.4\jackson-databind-2.15.4.jar;C:\Users\matth\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-core\2.15.4\jackson-core-2.15.4.jar;C:\Users\matth\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-annotations\2.15.4\jackson-annotations-2.15.4.jar;C:\Users\matth\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-hateoas\3.2.5\spring-boot-starter-hateoas-3.2.5.jar;C:\Users\matth\.m2\repository\org\springframework\hateoas\spring-hateoas\2.2.2\spring-hateoas-2.2.2.jar;C:\Users\matth\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-aop\6.1.6\spring-aop-6.1.6.jar;C:\Users\matth\.m2\repository\org\springframework\plugin\spring-plugin-core\3.0.0\spring-plugin-core-3.0.0.jar;C:\Users\matth\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-web\3.2.5\spring-boot-starter-web-3.2.5.jar;C:\Users\matth\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-json\3.2.5\spring-boot-starter-json-3.2.5.jar;C:\Users\matth\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\datatype\jackson-datatype-jdk8\2.15.4\jackson-datatype-jdk8-2.15.4.jar;C:\Users\matth\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\datatype\jackson-datatype-jsr310\2.15.4\jackson-datatype-jsr310-2.15.4.jar;C:\Users\matth\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\module\jackson-module-parameter-names\2.15.4\jackson-module-parameter-names-2.15.4.jar;C:\Users\matth\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-tomcat\3.2.5\spring-boot-starter-tomcat-3.2.5.jar;C:\Users\matth\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-core\10.1.20\tomcat-embed-core-10.1.20.jar;C:\Users\matth\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-el\10.1.20\tomcat-embed-el-10.1.20.jar;C:\Users\matth\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-websocket\10.1.20\tomcat-embed-websocket-10.1.20.jar;C:\Users\matth\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-web\6.1.6\spring-web-6.1.6.jar;C:\Users\matth\.m2\repository\io\micrometer\micrometer-observation\1.12.5\micrometer-observation-1.12.5.jar;C:\Users\matth\.m2\repository\io\micrometer\micrometer-commons\1.12.5\micrometer-commons-1.12.5.jar;C:\Users\matth\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-webmvc\6.1.6\spring-webmvc-6.1.6.jar;C:\Users\matth\.m2\repository\com\jayway\jsonpath\json-path\2.9.0\json-path-2.9.0.jar;C:\Users\matth\.m2\repository\net\minidev\json-smart\2.5.1\json-smart-2.5.1.jar;C:\Users\matth\.m2\repository\net\minidev\accessors-smart\2.5.1\accessors-smart-2.5.1.jar;C:\Users\matth\.m2\repository\org\ow2\asm\asm\9.6\asm-9.6.jar;C:\Users\matth\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-core\6.1.6\spring-core-6.1.6.jar;C:\Users\matth\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-jcl\6.1.6\spring-jcl-6.1.6.jar com.mistermorse.flawlessbeansjavaspringapi.FlawlessBeansJavaSpringApiApplication
14:41:06.377 [main] WARN org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext -- Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoGeneral': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'mongoProperties': No qualifying bean of type 'com.mistermorse.flawlessbeansjavaspringapi.config.MongoProperties' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoGeneral': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'mongoProperties': No qualifying bean of type 'com.mistermorse.flawlessbeansjavaspringapi.config.MongoProperties' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:787)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:767)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:145)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:508)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1419)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:599)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:975)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:962)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:624)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.<init>(AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.java:93)
    at com.mistermorse.flawlessbeansjavaspringapi.FlawlessBeansJavaSpringApiApplication.main(FlawlessBeansJavaSpringApiApplication.java:21)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.mistermorse.flawlessbeansjavaspringapi.config.MongoProperties' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1880)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1406)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1353)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:784)
    ... 15 more

Process finished with exit code 1

I don't think my POM is related, but I'll include it in the name of MRE fullness.
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.5</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.mistermorse</groupId>
    <artifactId>flawless-beans-java-spring-api</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>flawless-beans-java-spring-api</name>
    <description>A REST API serving data to an app for my favorite local coffee shop.</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-hateoas</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>

I'd be immensely grateful for any help. I wish I knew how the fetching from the file occurred behind the scenes, and if it could be triggered manually; it wouldn't be elegant, but it might help me understand the flow.

You may need to add additional Spring annotations to your MongoProperties class. Have you tried adding either @Configuration or @Component to that class? These are the same annotations that you used on your MongoGeneral class. I know that the @Configuration annotation is what tells Spring to expect beans to be declared in that class
